# How can I access from an app deploy on Bluemix to on-premise database DB2?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I configured a Secure Gateway and I'm trying to connect to an on-premise database. I'm receiving this error message :

```
[err] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.12.55] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
6/3/2016 5:49:31 PM ERR App or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - insufficient data (-1).  Message: Insufficient data. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
6/3/2016 5:49:31 PM ERR App [err]   
App [err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:319)
App [err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:461)
App [err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:456)
App [err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.b(z.java:242)
App [err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.c(z.java:268)
App [err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.c(z.java:381)
App [err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.v(z.java:1149)
App [err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:45)
App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.n(b.java:1251)
App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1123)
App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.d(b.java:717)
App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:703)
App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:391)
App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:320)
App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214)
App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:460)
App [err]   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
App [err]   at wasdev.sample.servlet.DBServlet.getTargetDBConnection(DBServlet.java:127)
App [err]   at wasdev.sample.servlet.DBServlet.doGet(DBServlet.java:60)
App [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
App [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
App [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
App [err]   at [internal classes]
App [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
App [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
App [err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not indicate a Secure Gateway issue.  Looking at the earlier instances of error experienced by others, it is either a 
Stale Connection issue
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/10120/what-could-cause-a-connection-refused-to-sqldb-db2-after-some-time.html    or
 Firewall issue or Network issue as in
[DB2 jdbc connection error Connection refused. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289409/db2-jdbc-connection-error-connection-refused-errorcode-4499-sqlstate-08001)
[I am getting " Operation timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001" connecting to remote DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866614/i-am-getting-operation-timed-out-errorcode-4499-sqlstate-08001-connecting)

Comment: Thanks it was an error from config file of the secure gateway.

Comment: Understanding that the problem is resolved after updating a config file setting.  Please confirm and provide some details on config file setting that caused the error.  Thanks.

Comment: im using the secure gateway with Watson analytics and Bluemix. I thought i can use only one autorisation file for the two SGW. But my secure gateway client use the autorisation file for the first listed SGW and for the second one it deny access. In the config file, ACL_FILE parameter must have contain the list of autorisation files.